# Sending simple goal in an unmapped environment

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can we send simple goal to robot in an unmapped environment (not traversed by robot earlier) using move_base package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60728/sending-simple-goal-in-an-unmapped-environment/) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately no. Both the current position of the robot and the goal pose need to be in a region that is marked as unoccupied in the map. You can try this for yourself (instructions are for Fuerte):

1. start the PR2 in Gazebo: `roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_wg_world.launch`
2. start move_base + gmapping: `roslaunch pr2_2dnav_slam pr2_2dnav.launch`
3. start RViz: `rosrun rviz rviz -d $(rospack find pr2_navigation_slam)/rviz/move_base_slam.vcg`
4. start teleop: `roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch`

Now you can try sending move_base commands using the "2D Nav Goal" button in RViz; nothing will happen, because the PR2 itself is still in unexplored space. Use the teleop window to move the PR2 around until it is well in explored space. Now sending goals in explored (and unoccupied) space should work, but sending goals in unexplored space does not.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-04-18**:
Ok, Thank you. I tried SLAM and then turtlebot_navigation package by setting up the navigation stack. It doesn't work for unexplored space. And observed results as mentioned above.